# Xamarin Azure Mobile Services App Permissions

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have a quick question I am trying to find an answer for but failed.

I built a Xamarin android app using Azure Mobile Services (Offline sync etc) and all works perfectly in Android Emulator but after I distributed the app, generated the APK and installed it on my device, I am not getting any data.

I realise that it could be anything so I need to run logcat and check what is going on, therefore I am not asking for the solution to this but I have a quick question.

> Do I need to grant any sort of permissions to the app as it is using
>   the internet on user's device?

In my manifest, I don't grant any permissions

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.pagesAndroid2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable the INTERNET permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The how-to page for Xamarin doesn't say so, but the [page for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#enable-internet) does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at somewhere I read that from Lollipop onwards the INTERNET permissions are by default included as Google thinks most apps need internet anyways - Trying to find the reference